# SQL Query to count IDs with exactly 91 duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a mySQL database of survey responses.  Each one has a userID, a questionID and the actual answer.  Now I'm trying to write a report that will tell me how many people actually completed the survey as opposed to stopped halfway through.  So I'm trying to figure out how to write a query that will count all of the userIDs that are duplicated exactly 91 times.

Be gentle, this is my first stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to group by having count(*) = 91

```
select userId from myTable group by userId having count(*) = 91
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't have data to test this, but this may help:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS userCount, userId
FROM tbl
GROUP BY userId
HAVING userCount = 91
```

Comment: I don't think the semantics of `>` match the requirement of "exactly 91 times". ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the questions are ordered, then you could check for the last question ID:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SurveyResponses WHERE QuestionId= [last_question_id]
```